# What would cause phpmyadmin to not show more than 30 rows?

Tags: phpmyadmin

The table itself holds over 700 rows - but changing the "show" form and submitting it does not show more than the first 30 rows.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is the default number of rows shown by phpmyadmin. You can change that limit to any number, for your case, 700 and at starting from 0.
You can find text fields to insert the number of rows and starting field.

i.e. Show 700 rows starting from record #0.

[image: See text fields here]

OR

Fire the query directly ,

```
 SELECT * FROM `tbl_name` LIMIT 0 , 700
```

Comment: Props for a UI screenshot! Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Thanks, KusH, but the problem is that's exactly what I'd tried - and for some reason it just returns the same 30 again even when I set it to 700. Is there something that would break it?